# scrapy proxy: User timeout caused connection failure

Tags: python, proxy, scrapy, request

When I send requests with my Scrapy spider, a `TimeoutError: User timeout caused connection failure` occurs, but the same proxy does work in plain Requests.I defined `process_response`  and `process_request` in middlewares to add random HTTP proxy to each request, but this don't work even with accessible proxy.

```
    def process_request(request, spider):
        proxy = get_proxy()
        if proxy:
            request.meta['proxy'] = get_proxy()
        else:
            return IgnoreRequest
        logging.info("proxy:" + request.meta['proxy'])
        return request
```

```
    def process_response(self, request, response, spider):

        if re.search(r'百度安全验证') is None:
            return response
        else:
            logging.info("ip: %s is banned!", request.meta['proxy'])
            proxy = get_proxy()
            if proxy:
                request.meta['proxy'] = proxy
                return request
            else:
                return IgnoreRequest
```

And I think `settings` can work well:

```
SPIDER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'tieba.middlewares.TiebaSpiderMiddleware': 1000,
}
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'tieba.middlewares.TiebaDownloaderMiddleware': 1000,
}
RETRY_TIMES = 2
DOWNLOAD_TIMEOUT = 10
```

There is no download delay.

I want the same proxy to work in Scrapy as it does in Requests.